# Understanding Twitter v2 API rate limits for filtered stream

Tags: twitter

I understand there is no real tweet limit in stream mode rather a limit for connections and filter changes. Is that correct?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overall Tweet cap limit on the [standard basic product track](https://developer.twitter.com/en/products/twitter-api/standard) of 500,000 Tweets per month with the v2 API.